# Is this program having any sequence point issues?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, sequence-points

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {  
       int i=7,j;
       j=(i++,++i,j*i); 
       return 0;
}
```

j=(i++,++i,j*i);Is this well defined ? Let me clear my doubt.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?  Can't you just do `i += 2; j *= i`?

Comment: @JeremyP:Just for learning c-concepts :-)

Comment: Who cares. You would never see this code in real life. It would not get through a code review as you would have to explain were the sequence points are and 80% of developers don;t know what a sequence point is.

Comment: See what Martin says?  All this obscure type of behaviour is just totally irrelevant to programming in the real World.  The only thing you need to know to cover all this stuff is to be really careful about expressions with side effects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This expression is OK because the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

```
(i++, ++i, j*i)
```

However do not confuse it with the following where the comma is not acting as a sequence point:

```
somefunction(i++, ++i, j*i)
```

---

> What about j = i++ * ++i

The multiplication operator is not a sequence point.

---

(*Excuse me hijacking your answer*)

From §3.4 of ISO 9899:1999 (C Standard):

> #### 3.4 behavior
>
> external appearance or action
>
> #### 3.4.1 implementation-defined behavior
>
> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made
>
> EXAMPLE An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit
>   when a signed integer is shifted right.
>
> #### 3.4.2 locale-specific behavior
>
> behavior that depends on local conventions of nationality, culture, and language that each
>   implementation documents
>
> EXAMPLE An example of locale-specific behavior is whether the islower function returns true for
>   characters other than the 26 lowercase Latin letters.
>
> #### 3.4.3 undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>
> NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
>   results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or
>   execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
>
> EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.
>
> #### 3.4.4 unspecified behavior
>
> behavior where this International Standard provides two or more possibilities and
>   imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance
>
> EXAMPLE An example of unspecified behavior is the order in which the arguments to a function are
>   evaluated.

Comment: Yes ! order of evaluation is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Jagan, I think it's actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: unspecified , undefined and implementation dependent.These terms are very dangerous.I use them interchangeably (i should not do).I feel better if you explain these words.

Comment: @Jagan: see the quote from the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It's well defined.
[sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

[comma operator in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: Undefined. There're no sequence points inside the expression and `i` is modified twice.

Answer (score 1):

In your code " ," will be work as sequence point.

so in this

```
j=(i++,++i,j*i);
```

expression would be work from left to right.
so at first i++ then ++i and then j*i

at the last j*i would be stored in j;

but lastly your result would be elegant because " j " have no predefined data
so undefined value would be stored in j.

if you don't use " () "

your code would be work as single statement such as

```
j=i++;
++i;
j*i;
```