# C pointers and functions

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C programming: is this undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450582/c-programming-is-this-undefined-behavior)
>   [Is this program having any sequence point issues ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590170/is-this-program-having-any-sequence-point-issues)

Hi,

I am running the following program

```
void print(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *e)
{

    printf("\n %d %d %d %d %d",*a,*b,*c,*d,*e);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    static int arr[] = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104};
    int *ptr=arr+1;
    print(++ptr,ptr--,ptr,ptr++,++ptr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I  thought I would be getting `99 99 98 98 100` as output but I am getting `100 100 100 99 100` as output. I cant understand why. Do pointers behave differently then normal variable when used with ++ or --(pre or postfix) operators. Can u please help me understand how the program is working

Comment: similiar questions asked before on SO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading and modifying `ptr` multiple times without a sequence point. This is undefined behavior. The compiler can emit any code it feels like. Don't do it.

Please note also that the order of evaluation of function arguments is not defined, so your `print` statement, even if it was well-defined, would not necessarily output what you think it would.

See this question [Is this undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450582/c-programming-is-this-undefined-behavior) for a similar issue.

Comment: See in particular point 4 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point.